# My WPF button needs to change the Content of a different button

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, uirefreshcontrol

I have 2 WPF buttons...when I click on one, I want the Content of the other button to change.  Right now, when I click on btn1, the btn2 Content does not change.

I have attempted a btn2.InvalidateVisual() but no help

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    count++; //count is a global int
    btn2.Content = string.Format("Btn 1 was clicked {0} times",count);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your method is called at all?

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus Gütter says. The code is ok. There have to be another problem. Show us your XAML.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).